# In Global Handler when i use SystemException in If condition then why SelectorNotFoundException not falling in Systemexception

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-activity, yetanotherforum, report-studio

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyc4T.png)[Query 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss3j8.png)
Query 1- I have used GlobalHandler.xaml file in my project and in GlobalHandler.xaml file  i have mentioned condition in if statement like -
errorInfo.Exception.GetType().Name.ToString.Contains("SystemException")
then {Do something}
but when i run main.xaml in which i have used one attach browser activity in sequence and that i put that sequence in Try block so that giving me SelectorNotFoundException because i have closed the browser and after that i am running main.xaml so my question is  why this selector exception is not falling in above condition System Exception part it always fall in else part  which is blank.
Please refer attach screenshots(Query Image 1) .

Comment: It is hard to read, please improve your text.

Comment: Query 2- In Global Handler.xaml file When i write IF statement (errorInfo.Exception.GetType().Name.ToString.Contains("SelectorNotFoundException") OR 
errorInfo.Exception.GetType().Name.ToString.Contains("SystemException")) 
then { if RetryCount <3  then {} Else {} }  
Else { Do Something }

my query is when i run main file and found selectorNotFoundException  then it will come to GlobalHandler.xaml  so here my loop execute it 4 times and giving message pop.then why it execute for 4 times instead of 3 times.
You can see in above screenshot . Attached screenshot in above Query 2 Image